# while loop content not passed through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

If I replace the while loop with custom values and variables, I can get the data pass through, however with while loop just can't and I wonder why? I've tested the while loop separately with hardcoded json value and it does return values from the database so cannot say the php is broken!

For the code below,

```
$display_string = "<table>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Name</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Phone</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Pricing</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Email</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";
```

This parts are showing in the ajax call initiated page but not the while loop below for the content:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){
   $display_string .= "<tr>";
   $display_string .= "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>".$row['Phone']."</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>".$row['pricing']."</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
   $display_string .= "</tr>";
}
```

Should I replace $row['Name'],$row['Phone'] and so forth with custom values like 'james','012567890' it works though!

This is how I echo `echo $display_string;`

This is the ajax call>

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".form").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "html",
      url: "search_subject.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        $(".the-return").html( $(data) );
        alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
        // window.location='success.php';

      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I did referred here:[AJAX fails while get data from while() loop in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727698/ajax-fails-while-get-data-from-while-loop-in-php)  but cannot get solution!

Query
    // Retrieve data from Query String
    $a=$data['sub'];
    $b=$data['rate2'];
    $subject_rate = array_intersect_key($b,$a);

```
foreach($subject_rate as $v=>$k) 
  {

      $key[]=$v;
    $value=$k;

  }
 $key2=implode(',',$key);


      //build query

//echo $query = "SELECT * FROM posts  WHERE subid IN  $key2";

   $query= "SELECT * FROM posts  WHERE subid IN ('$key2')";  
   $qry_result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: first post your actual query along with the table schema, you may have misspelled something there and as well it is case sensitive so Name isn't the same as name. As well you should consider just passing back json instead of html, and then build your html with javascript as it offers more flexibility with your data and also reduces the payload.

Comment: You mean to say the SQL, HTML,is working but not PHP?

Comment: @Augwa, posted the query but i dont think the problem is in it as it works  when I tested. It just not being passed through to another page.. I did try passing through json though previously and it read 'undefined' output.

Comment: @Aviz, I would say SQL,HTML and PHP working but not being able to pass through another page all the while loop data!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> mysql_fetch_assoc()

instead of

> mysql_fetch_array()

And also dont forget to echo $display_string on "search_subject.php" file

Comment: now can! I never knew this brings so much of difference! Thanks alot

Comment: You are welcome .. Silly errors are pain in the a** sometimes

Comment: how does this solve the OPs problem? mysql_fetch_array() gets the same stuff as mysql_fetch_assoc() except it also have the column by index as well ... so if the table has 3 columns `id, name, status` then the array will contain the following keys `[ 'id', 'name', 'status', 0, 1, 2 ]`

Comment: He dint specify the Result Type with   mysql_fetch_array($qry_result, MYSQL_ASSOC)

Comment: yes, but by default it does `MYSQL_BOTH` which does `MYSQL_ASSOC` and `MYSQL_NUM`. but if that fixed @sweety problem great ... I personally don't understand how it did though.

Comment: Looking at his code he wants an the result in associative array format so he should specify MYSQL_ASSOC or use the mysql_fetch_assoc() function  ... By the way MYSQL and MYSQLIi are slowly depreciating .. The new way to go is PDO ... Thats what php.net says ..